# Given $A,B$ square matrices and $AB = I + B$ : Prove $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A,B$ square matrices of order $n$ greater or equal to $2$ , $AB = I + B$ : Prove $AB=BA$.

what I am trying to do is :
$AB = I+B \implies AB-B=I \implies (A-I)B = I$

but then I got stuck XD any ideas?

Comment: i think you need the fact that the matrices have an order

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i prove that $AB=BA$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540130/how-can-i-prove-that-ab-ba) the hypothesis is the same if you exchange $A,B$ and replace one of them with its opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AB=I+B$

$AB-B=I$

$(A-I)B=I$

So $(A-I)$ and $B$ are inverse of each other

$\implies B(A-I)=I$

$\implies(A-I)B=B(A-I)$

$\implies AB-B=BA-B$

So, $AB=BA$

Comment: It was a duplicate (up to notations).

Comment: for (A−I) and B to be inverse of each other we must show that B(A-I) also equal to I and not assume it, don't we?

Comment: $XY=I$ already shows that $X^{-1}=Y$, i.e both are inverses, implying that $XY=YX$. There is nothing we are assuming here.

Comment: on my textbook we are told that To prove that two matrices are inverses of each other, you need to show that when you multiply them together in either order, you get the identity matrix. i.e AB = BA = I, so just one direction is not enough it says

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i should help you there